# Custom Android MediaController via MediaController hack. Necessary?

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I am using the VideoView object to play a video in an Android app I'm building. I don't want to use the standard MediaController but wish to implement my own. It doesn't need to have anything fancy or extra but I need to be able to control the placement and look of controls precisely. I came up with the following (UGLY!) "solution". I say "solution" because some other things seem to go wrong now and I'm not sure yet whether this has to do with the way I solved it (will update post if I find out). I'm now doing the following:

- Use a standard VideoView object
- Subclass MediaController
- Override hide(), show(), etc methods
- In overridden setMediaPlayer method I keep a reference to the active MediaPlayer so I can pause/play/etc
- Duplicate almost all regular MediaController behavior in the class (except the graphics part) and ignore the methods in the parent class.

I want to use the default VideoView and not write my own (I tried this and it took a long time and gave unexpected behavior). What I'm basically doing is having this subclass of a MediaController pose as a MediaController. It's like having two almost identical classes in one class. The original MediaController class is only used so that I can pass the subclassed object to the VideoView. Seems really awkward. What is the right approach for this?

Joris

Answer (score 0):

I actually am pretty dumb. All the methods I use in the MediaController subclass that access the MediaPlayer are methods that are directly accessible in the VideoView (getCurrentDuration(), getBufferPercentage(), pause(), start(), etc). So I can just make my MediaController a subclass of Object and have pass the VideoView in the constructor so I can access the same functionality.